# UPSERT from table with different table sizes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm getting the error:

`ERROR: column "some_col_name" does not exist Hint: There is a column named "some_col_name" in table "usert_test", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

On `UPSERT` The cause of this error is that the source table (read in from API) doesn't always have the same number of fields as the table I'm looking to UPSERT. Within the UPSERT process is there a way to handle this? So far I've tried the below:

```sql
INSERT INTO scratch."usert_test" (many_cols)
SELECT *
FROM scratch.daily_scraper
ON CONFLICT (same_unique_id)
    DO UPDATE
SET 
 many_fields = excluded.many_fields;
```

Comment: What are `many_fields`, `many_cols` and especially `some_col_name`? Please post a concrete query and the exact error message you get for it, as well as the table definitions of `usert_test` and `daily_scraper`.

Answer (score 0):

Name each column specifically in every instance.

```
    insert into scratch."usert_test" (column_name1, column_name2, column_name3,column_name3)
        select cola, colb, colc, colf
          from scratch.daily_scraper 
            on conflict (column_name1, column_name4)
            do update
               set 
                   column_name3  = excluded.column_name3
                 , column_name2  = excluded.column_name2;
```

How ever many columns you have properly name every one. (IMHO) As you should always do.